# Is there an API to interract with porjects?

Tags: python-3.x, django, onlyoffice

I'm developing a workflow-based application in Django.
The purpose of this application is to grab some data about projects, and to create a project in a scheduler application.

My corporate is testing "ONLYOFFICE Projects" for scheduling / projects managements.

I've to import some Trello based projects,  and add some projects from my django-based application.

Is it possible to call an API entry point to create a project, manage users, groups...
in ONLYOFFICE ? I've not seen anything in the docs...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> I've not seen anything in the docs...

All available methods can be found on the ONLYOFFCIE web site.
https://api.onlyoffice.com/portals/section/project

Comment: I had not found this page - Thanks !